# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Computer Science's [second moderator election](https://cs.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Discrete lizard]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6162226140413952/0).

Comment: Congratulations, and welcome to the fold!

Comment: Congratulations, Discrete Lizard!

Comment: @Raphael and D.W. Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: @Evil thx for volunteering and hey everyone hope to see you all in chat sometimes, just remember sometimes theres more to life than SE rep _wink_ ;)